# Django endless pagination with a request.method == 'POST'?

Tags: ajax, post, django-endless-pagination

I'm trying to get [Django Endless pagination](http://code.google.com/p/django-endless-pagination/) to work on a search form. 
All the examples and tutorials I've seen online show how to do it with a simple `.all()` queryset, but I need to filter out by the search results that I've had in the POST.

Here's how my view looks like for now:

```
@page_template("core/search_box.html")
def search(request,template = "core/search.html",page_template = "core/search_box.html",extra_context = None):
if request.is_ajax():
    #template=page_template()
    #users = Skill_User.objects.filter(skill__name__icontains=content).order_by('-level')
    #return render_to_response( template , {'page_template': page_template,'menu_home_active':True, 'form':search_form, 'result':users} , context_instance )
    return HttpResponse("AJAX")
elif request.method == 'POST':
    search_form = SearchForm( request.POST )
    # If Form is Valid
    if search_form.is_valid():
        type  = search_form.cleaned_data['type']
        content  = search_form.cleaned_data['content']
        print 'CONTENT ' + str(content)
        if (type == 'O'):
            users = Skill_User.objects.filter(skill__name__icontains=content).order_by('-level')
        elif (type == 'G'):
            users= {}
    return render_to_response( template , {'page_template': page_template,'menu_home_active':True, 'form':search_form, 'result':users} , context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
else:
    return HttpResponse("NOT OK")
```

So the search is done on POST. But how can I pass this search POST thingy to the ajax query that's done by the endless-pagination plug-in ? I commented out everything in the `request.ajax()` part, I just need "users" to be filled by the same data as after the POST request.  Basically, for now when I scroll down I have "AJAX" showing up, and I'd like the rest of my query as well.

Any ideas? I haven't found anything obvious online about that. I come from a PHP background, and I would think about `$_SESSION[]` variables. Is there something similar in Django?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's doable with a simple `request.session[""]` object.